# how can I convert String to Data

Tags: ios, swift, windows-1251

I have next:

```
deviceName = String.init(bytes: temp.prefix(upTo: index), encoding: .windowsCP1251)
```

where temp - `[UInt8]`. My question is: how can I convert this string back to `Data`?
I'm trying to convert like this:

```
newDataName = Data(newName.windowsCP1251)
```

But result is:

> Value of type `String` has no member `windowsCP1251`

It is works with converting using `utf8`, but it shows russian characters incorrect. I need to use `windowsCP1251` only:

```
newDataName = Data(newName.utf8)
```

Comment: `newName.data(using: .windowsCP1251)`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Maybe this is what you looking for:

```
newDataName = newName.data(using: .windowsCP1251)
```

Comment: oh yes, thanks, it's works